# Jackrabbit dateformat for comparison

Tags: java, xpath, jackrabbit

I am using Jackrabbit to store my documents. 
Now I would like to search for documents that were created e.g. after a specific date using XPATH. To do so, I tried something like:

```
String dateString = date.toString();
//element(*,nt:file)[@jcr:created >= xs:dateTime(dateString)]
```

date is an object of class `java.util.Date`
dateString gets formatted as: *Wed Mar 16 00:00:00 CET 2011*

But this is giving me an `InvalidQueryException`, indicating that the dateString is wrong:

> Invalid query: Lexical error at line
>   1, column 136.  Encountered: "0" (48),
>   after : ":" for statement

So the question is: What is the correct format of a date for xs:dateTime ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xs:dateTime` uses a specific pattern - see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp). So instead of using date.toString(), to produce that format, you would need to use a suitable `DateFormat`. Something like this:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = format.format(date);
```

However, it appears that the constructor for xs:dateTime in fact requires two args: one for date and one for time. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xpath-functions-20041029/#func-dateTime).

So I would guess you could use this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = df.format(date);
String timeString = tf.format(date);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It looks like this is a correct answer, but when trying this I get the message: `Invalid query: Unable to parse string literal for xs:dateTime: 2011-02-28T00:00:00`.

Comment: Try the two arg constructor for dateTime

Comment: Using the two args constructor didn't help. Still getting the parsing error. But I found the correct format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`. Since I found that out by reading through your links, I will accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

For Jackrabbit this worked for me:`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`
(`2015-12-16T15:16:50.465-02:00`) when some previous code had taken a Calendar and done:`prop.getValue().getString()`

Couldn't get Z to work ("Unparseable date").

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness:

I found another (Jackrabbit/JCR dependend) way to get a correctly formatted date string:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
String dateString = ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createValue(cal).getString();
```

This dateString can be used with the single arg constructor of `xs:dateTime`

Comment: And to be just a bit more complete, get the instance of `ValueFactory` from the `JackrabbitSession.getValueFactory()` method so you don't need a reference to the implementation class.

Answer (score 1):

Also I have some problems with JAckRabbit date format and I needed to get some entities between two dates :

@createdDate >= xs:dateTime(startDate)
 @createdDate <= xs:dateTime(endDate)

What I noticed is :

1. using format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' to parse the date gave incorrect results( also it should be yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ) but you get for example :
   2012-01-04T23:59:59.999+0200 instead of
   2012-01-04T23:59:59.999+02:00 (saved in JCR)
2. Solution with ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createValue(cal).getString() works.